# JQuery, a new Selection using the results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to me do this?

```
<img id="example" src="anything.jpg" title="something" class="abc" />
```

---

```
$('.abc').each(function(){

   //test if this result is something
   if( $(this)...(???)...('[src^=anything]')) == 'anything.jpg'){

   }

   //another Jquery selector test for this one    
   if( $(this)...(???)...('#example').size() > 0){

   }


});
```

This is just an example, what I need is pretty more complex.. But I would like to know if there is a way to make other jQuery selector test in the result of a first selector.. since "find" will find the children of $(this).. and .parent() get alot of brothers..

See what I mean?
Do you have any idea?

---

---

So sorry.. let me try again..

$('div').each();

get all "div", right?

But now in that function I need to make another "test" check if div class is "red" or "blue"..

See?

I need to test something else of the result based in Jquery selector..

I know I could do:

`class = $(this).attr('class');` and `then if(class=="blue"){}` .. But I would like to do `$('this[class=blue]').size()>0){}`

Comment: @user534312 Could you give a little more info. I'm confused about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) filter operates on a found set to detect if something is true or not.

The jQuery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method will further pare down a found set based on criteria.

```
var allDivs   = $('div');
var greenOnes = allDivs.filter('.green');
var redOnes   = allDivs.filter('.red'  );
```

Comment: @progz, the other day you had some solution for vertically align a div can you give me that link , i need it now.

Comment: @gov Googling for `phrogz vertical align` will give it to you. :p

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the [is method](http://docs.jquery.com/Is):

```
$('.abc').each(function() {
    $(this).is('[src^=anything]')
});
```

This is fairly simple though, but I can't really tell what you are trying to do by the description. Maybe this is enough to get you started though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) methods to filter/search within a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(this).is('[src^="anything"]') ) {
}
elseif( $("#example").size() > 0) {
}
```

You could put $("#example") in a variable outside of the loop and then reference it inside the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.src.indexOf("anything") === 0) {
    // source starts with 'anything'
}

if($("#example").length) {
    // since there can be only one #example
    // in a *valid* document
}
```

Based on your edit:

```
if($(this).hasClass("blue")) {
    ...
}
```

?